# What does it mean to "open code" something in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

In the SBCL user manual there are several references to the term "[open code](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Efficiency)".  Common Lisp hackers also use this term when referring to optimizing code.

Could you please explain what it means to "open code" something and give an example of how it works?

Comment: Section 4.5 explains it pretty explicitly: it's inlining. There's even an example. Is there part of it that is unclear?

Comment: I overlooked that, sorry.  I also read literature where the term "open code" seemed to be used for something else, hence the need for clarification.  It looks like this term is mostly used in the SBCL community.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## What It Is

[Open-coding, AKA inlining](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Open-Coding-and-Inline-Expansion), means replacing function calls with inline assembly.
The idea is that [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm) and [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm) are expensive (they require saving and restoring the stack &c) and replacing them with the few operations which constitute the function can be beneficial.

E.g., the function [`1+`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm) is a single instruction when the argument is a [`fixnum`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_fixnum.htm) (which it usually is in practice), so turning the funcall into the two parallel branches ([`fixnum`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_fixnum.htm) and otherwise) would be a win.

## How to Control it

### Declarations

They user can control this optimization explicitly by the [`inline`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_inline.htm)
declaration (which implementations are free to ignore).

The user can also influence this optimization by the [`optimize`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_optimi.htm) declaration.

Both will affect inlining the code of a function defined just as a function (see below).

### Macros

The "old" way is to implement the function as a macro. E.g., instead of

```
(defun last1f (list)
  (car (last list)))
```

write

```
(defmacro last1m (list)
  `(car (last ,list)))
```

and `last1m` will be always open-coded. The problem with this approach is that you cannot use `last1m` as a function - you cannot pass it to, say, [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm).

Thus Common Lisp has an alternative way - [compiler macros](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_define.htm), which tell the compiler how to transform the form before compiling it:

```
(define-compiler-macro last1f (list)
   ;; use in conjunction with (defun last1f ...)
   `(car (last ,list)))
```

See also the excellent examples in the aforelinked CLHS page.

## Its Effects on Optimization

A comment asked about the *effects* of inlining, i.e., what optimizations result from it. E.g., constant propagation in addition to eliminating a function call.

The answer to this question is left to *implementations*.
IOW, the CL *standard* does *not* specify what optimizations *must* be done.

**However**, [Minimal Compilation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_bbb.htm) implies that
*if* an implementation does *something* (e.g. constant folding), it *will* be
done for [compiler macros](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_define.htm) too.

For more details, you should compare the results of
[`disassemble`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_disass.htm) with and
without the declarations and whatnot and see the effects.

For explanations, you should ask the *vendor* (e.g., by using the appropriate
tag here - e.g., `sbcl`, `clisp`, &c).

Comment: Thank you @sds, does open coding has a relationship with "compiler macros" as well or is it irrelevant?

Comment: You are welcome; please see edit about the macros and compiler macros

Comment: are function calls so expensive in CL?  in C++, inline functions allow the compiler to optimize across function boundaries, and this optimization opportunity is the true speedup of inlining there.  is that different in CL?

Comment: @SusanneOberhauser: it really depends on the specific implementation, but, generally speaking, a function call does have have cost in any language (stack monipulation)

Comment: yes I understand that there is a small overhead for function calls in any language, including C.  now the very nice response elaborates on that extensively.  however.  the _significant_ benefit of inlining lies in the compiler being able to do (for example) const propagation of some computation out of the inlined function body to before the loop which invokes the function.  and the accepted response doesn't even mention that core benefit of inline optimization.

Comment: @SusanneOberhauser: I added section _ Effects on Optimization_ - does this address your concern?

Comment: it does, thank you :-)